# Calling a function from a static class

Tags: c++

So the title is somewhat misleading. But its exactly what I am trying to do. I created a small case scenario. This case works in Visual Studio but when trying it on Mingw I get an error. Here is the case. I am trying to call a function inside a cpp file from a static method which resides in a different cpp file. This is just rough code which will get my point across.

File:foo.h

```
#ifndef FOO_H_INCLUDED
#define FOO_H_INCLUDED

#include <iostream>

struct foo
{
    int someMethod();
};


#endif // FOO_H_INCLUDED
```

File: foo.cpp

```
#include "foo.h"

int someFunction()
{
    std::cout << "SomeFunction";
    return 0;
}

int foo::someMethod()
{
  std::cout << "foo called";
  return 0;
}
```

File:main.cpp

```
void myfunction()
{

}

struct bar
{
    static void somebar()
    {
       someFunction(); //error: 'someFunction' was not declared in this scope
       myfunction(); //OK

    }
};

int main()
{

}
```

My question is why am I getting an error on someFunction();
This is my compiler output

```
g++.exe -Wall -std=c++98 -g -std=c++11 -I..\..\..\mingw64\include -c C:\Users\peeru\TestCodeBlocks\foo.cpp -o obj\Debug\foo.o
C:\Users\peeru\TestCodeBlocks\foo.cpp: In function 'int someFunction()':
C:\Users\peeru\TestCodeBlocks\foo.cpp:6:1: warning: no return statement in function returning non-void [-Wreturn-type]
 }
 ^
C:\Users\peeru\TestCodeBlocks\foo.cpp: In member function 'int foo::someMethod()':
C:\Users\peeru\TestCodeBlocks\foo.cpp:11:1: warning: no return statement in function returning non-void [-Wreturn-type]
 }
 ^
g++.exe -Wall -std=c++98 -g -std=c++11 -I..\..\..\mingw64\include -c C:\Users\peeru\TestCodeBlocks\main.cpp -o obj\Debug\main.o
C:\Users\peeru\TestCodeBlocks\main.cpp: In static member function 'static void bar::somebar()':
C:\Users\peeru\TestCodeBlocks\main.cpp:14:21: error: 'someFunction' was not declared in this scope
        someFunction();
                     ^
Process terminated with status 1 (0 minute(s), 0 second(s))
1 error(s), 2 warning(s) (0 minute(s), 0 second(s))
```

Any suggestions ?

Comment: `someFunction` is not visible in Main.cpp. Add `extern int someFunction()` at the top of Main.cpp, or add in foo.h and include foo.h in Main.cpp

Comment: Also of note: `foo::someMethod` is not `static`, and thus will require a `foo` object.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As the compiler says, `someFunction` hasn't been declared in `main.cpp`, only in a separate translation unit, `foo.cpp`. Functions need to be declared before use.

Add a declaration in either `main.cpp`, or a header included from both:

```
int someFunction();
```

You also need to return something from the functions that claim to return `int`, as the other warnings say.

Answer (score 1):

You have to provide a declaration for the function in `main.cpp` too, modify the `foo.h` header accordingly:

```
#ifndef FOO_H_INCLUDED
#define FOO_H_INCLUDED

#include <iostream>

int someFunction();

struct foo
{
    int someMethod();
};


#endif // FOO_H_INCLUDED
```

and add `#include "foo.h"` in `main.cpp`.

I am not sure why MSVC++ compiled without complaining, though.

Comment: That was what I was curious about.

Answer (score 0):

Method `someFunction` and all others are declared as returning type `int`. So, add `return 0` at the end of functions or declare them as void. And you cannot call non static function from static function.

Comment: That explains the warnings; but the question is about the error.

Comment: That has totally nothing to do with the answer

Comment: "you cannot call non static function from static function" - nonsense, of course you can. The only problem here is that the function hasn't been declared.

Comment: I know it looks simple. Visual Studio has no problem with it

Answer (score 0):

You declared someFunction() in foo.cpp, but not in main.cpp.  When main.cpp is compiling, it doesn't know the declaration of someFunction(), so it fails.

You need to:

1. add `int someFunction();` to the top of main.cpp
2. add `int someFunction();` to the foo.h file, and then `#include "foo.h"` in main.cpp